# What is the meaning of the expression "we have a ball game"?

Tags: expressions

I've heard the phrase, "We gotta ball game". It could also be "We have a ball game". But I don't understand the meaning of "having a ball game". If anyone has heard this expression before, please help. I'm so very confused after guessing about this for a long time. The person who said it couldn't even tell me what he meant by this.

Comment: Since even the person who said this to OP couldn't explain what he meant, I'm afraid I'm duty-bound to vote to close as "too localised".

Comment: @Fumble: I think your vote to close is premature. People often repeat expressions they've heard without completely understanding their meaning.

Comment: @Callithumpian: Yes, but it seems very likely that in this case the *original* speaker not only didn't understand what he himself meant - he was quite probably misrepeating some version of *"We've got a whole new ball game"*. I find no instances in Google Books of *"We've got a ball game"* followed by, for example, *now, going* or any other word consistent with it not being a straightforward literal statement (as in *...to go to this afternoon*).

Comment: I agree with closing this; the answers illustrate how unclear the question is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prototypical phrase is "We've got ourselves a whole new ball game"; often meaning that the situation has so changed that one has a sporting chance of success in whatever the situation is.  Without the "whole new" part, it means that regardless of whether the situation has changed, one has a chance of success.

[Idiomquest.com](http://www.idiomquest.com/learn/idiom/whole-new-ball-game/) says, regarding "whole new ball game":

> When the state of affairs change dramatically and presents new opportunities.

***Edit:*** As others have mentioned, a phrase like *[we have a ball game](http://espn.go.com/blog/dallas/colleges/post/_/id/4676243/do-we-have-a-ball-game-all-of-a-sudden)* may mean that a contest has developed, in a game that formerly looked like a walkover.  That might be what was meant by the person who said it, and of course is the sort of thing meant by the phrase *a sporting chance* in my answer above.

Looking at [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+a+ball+game%2Cnew+ball+game%2Cus+a+ball+game%2Chave+a+ball+game&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it appears that the phrase *new ball game* is found a hundred times as frequently as any of *got a ball game, us a ball game,* or *have a ball game*; and looking at links from ngrams, the contest-has-developed sense is surprisingly rare, but of course does occur.

Comment: I agree this is a common idiom taken from sports jargon, but I don't believe this is the phrase referred to by the OP.

Comment: @Callithumpian, I've updated my answer to include that alternate possibility

Comment: Ok. I retracted my downvote. Though I have mixed feelings about having what I think is my correct interpretation of the question folded into someone else's answer. Since your answer was already chosen, I suppose it's all good.

Comment: @Callithumpian: Perhaps you'd be so good as to track down a few more instances where OP's "cut-down" version could be anything different to, say, a boxing commentator saying *"We've got a boxing match"* halfway through the fight. Which would simply mean that the earlier rounds weren't much of a contest, but would in no way imply that *"We've got a boxing match"* was something worthy of consideration here on ELU. Whereas jwpat7 is spot-on in pointing out that *"...whole new ball game"* is very much part of the general lexicon outside sports commentating.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: See my [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54737/5822). Jwpat7 may be spot-on regarding _whole new ball game_. Unfortunately, that phrase has nothing to do with this particular question.

Comment: @Callithumpian: You're right, and I was wrong. I can't reverse my vote to close unless it actually gets closed so I can vote to reopen. But I shall gladly upvote your answer as well as jwpat7's - yours because it covers the very specific usage, and his because it also covers the more common idiom which IMHO is likely to influence how far into general parlance this usage might get.

Comment: @Callithumpian, I too upvoted your answer, because it expresses a *possibility* of what was meant within question; but the person using the expression not knowing what he meant to say makes the point somewhat moot.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'll take you up on that offer to vote to reopen.

Comment: @jwpat7: That was what I thought when I first voted to close, but Callithumpian's dilligence in proving me wrong about the validity of the expression in the first place has made me doubt my own judgement in all things! I still think it's a highly localised question (because I'm UK, and it's obviously an (emerging?) US usage). But we answer questions where the OP doesn't know what some expression means, so why should it bother us if the person OP heard using it doesn't know either? Always providing it turns out to be a valid expression in the first place, obviously.

Answer (score 5):

American sportscasters and sports fans will often say *[we have a ball game](http://espn.go.com/blog/dallas/colleges/post/_/id/4676243/do-we-have-a-ball-game-all-of-a-sudden)* (often preceded by *now* or *suddenly*) when two sports teams seem equally matched or when the score of a game gets close, thus avoiding a blowout. A blowout could be seen as the opposite of *a ball game* in this sense. Another way of thinking about it is that *having a ball game* is synonymous with having a competitive matchup that is fair and interesting to watch.

This phrase has been borrowed from sports jargon and is commonly applied to other competitions, such as [a close political race](http://www.city-data.com/forum/pittsburgh/183156-now-we-have-ball-game-pg.html).

**Edit:**

At @Fumble's request, here's some more examples of the phrase used idiomatically:

- from a [real estate](http://books.google.com/books?id=dFVTB2gmtwkC&pg=PA195&dq=%22now%20we%20have%20a%20ball%20game%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oQEST-GVK6qu0AHQ6dUY&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22now%20we%20have%20a%20ball%20game%22&f=false) manual
- from [a novel](http://books.google.com/books?ei=pAQST4a4Banc0QGn0IySAw&id=p_VpWfJtW-4C&dq=the%20object%20lesson%20orlando&q=ball%20game#search_anchor)
- from another [close election](http://www.erepublik.com/en/article/now-this-is-a-ball-game--1361021/1/20)

Answer (score 1):

When "we DON'T have a ball game," it suggests that the "match" is one-sided. "It's a ball game again," or "we've got a ball game" means that a recent event "suddenly" made a formerly lopsided game competitive.

Say one team is leading another in an American baseball game 5-0. In professional games, at least, that represents almost a sure win for the first team. But suppose the occurrence of the unlikely event that the trailing team hits a "grand slam" home run (for four points). Now, it's 5-4, not 5-0, and the formerly one-sided game is suddenly "competitive" (especially since the trailing team is still "at bat," and might add more runs).

Answer (score -1):

Basically,

> We have a ball game

is just a shortened form of:

> We have a ball game *to attend to*.

Similary, "*I have a meeting.*" is a shortened version of "*I have a meeting to attend to*".

People tend to shorten expressions for convenience.

Comment: Given that the OP said, "The person who said it couldn't even tell me what he meant by this." it's probably metaphorical, not this literal.